# Fragment Evaluation Error

Tags: scala, lift, specs, mongodb-scala

Can someone tell me what "Fragment evaluation error" means, or where I might look for solutions?  I sometimes (but not always) get lots of these errors (without changing my code):

```
[error] ! Fragment evaluation error
[error]     ThrowableException: Could not initialize class code.model.Post$  (FutureTask.java:138)
[error] code.model.PostSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcZ$sp(PostSpec.scala:68)
[error] code.model.PostSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PostSpec.scala:51)
[error] code.model.PostSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PostSpec.scala:51)
```

Line 68 of PostSpec is the first line in the (specs2) test that references the Post model companion object:

```
val test4 = Post.fixJValue(toextract4).extract[Selection]
```

I'm using Scala 2.9.0-1.

Also: I have no idea whether it matters, but Post is a net.liftweb.mongodb.record.MongoRecord class companion object:

```
object Post extends Post with MongoMetaRecord[Post] { ... }
```

Comment: Here's a convenient link to the [source code of FutureTask.java](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java.html).  Line 138 is a call to sync.innerRun(): 
 `public void run() {
        sync.innerRun();
    }`

Comment: I have also been having issues with mongo and specs2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a specs2 specification, `Fragments` are pieces of the specification. A `Fragment` can be a `Text`, an `Example`, a `Step`.

Some fragments, like `Example` and `Step` are meant to be executed and are supposed to catch Exceptions so that they can be marked as failures. But they won't catch `Error`s (except `AssertionError`s). So if an Example throws an `OutOfMemoryError`, this will be reported as a Fragment evaluation error.

Other fragments, like `Text` fragments are not supposed to throw exceptions when being evaluated. If they do, you will get the same `Fragment evaluation error` message.

Without seeing the full specification it's hard for me to say what's happening there but I suspect that you had a non-Exception type thrown in the body of an `Example`. But I have more questions than answers for now:

- where is `test4` declared? Inside the specification body? Inside a `Context` case class?
- since errors happen intermittently, are you sure you always have a proper mongodb context? Maybe your specification examples are being executed concurrently on the same mongo db instance?

Comment: `test4` is declared inside a specification body.  In this case, the method that I'm calling (`Post.fixJValue(JValue):JValue`) is just a convenience method that was (...well...) convenient to place inside the `Post` object -- it actually does no work on mongodb.

Comment: Maybe you could try to declare the val as a lazy val so that its evaluation really happens during the example execution.

Comment: Your note about "context" got me thinking and searching in a new direction, however.  I'll bet that initialization of the MongoMetaRecord object is causing problems.  And, I'll bet that moving this method out of that object will resolve the issue.