# Simple scalatra-test specs2 example throws Exception

Tags: scala, scalatra, specs2

I'm getting this exception when running the scalatra specs2 example from the [scalatra docs](http://www.scalatra.org/2.0/book/#Testing):

```
ThrowableException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer()I (FutureTask.java:138)
```

Here is the test code (starting on line 5, skipping imports):

```
class MyAppTest extends MutableScalatraSpec {
  addServlet(classOf[MyApp], "/*") 

  "GET / on AdminApp" should {
    "return status 200" in {
      get("/") { 
        status must_== 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the app definition:

```
class MyApp extends ScalatraServlet {

  get("/") {
    "aloha"
  }
}
```

I'm using scalatra-specs2 2.0.4 and scala 2.9.1.  I'm running an embedded jetty server using xsbt-web-plugin 0.2.10 with sbt 0.11.2.  The test was executed using `sbt test`.

Here is the full trace:

```
[info] GET / on AdminApp should
[error] ! Fragment evaluation error
[error]     ThrowableException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer()I (FutureTask.java:138)
[error] org.eclipse.jetty.testing.HttpTester.generate(HttpTester.java:225)
[error] org.scalatra.test.ScalatraTests$class.submit(ScalatraTests.scala:46)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest.submit(MyAppTest.scala:5)
[error] org.scalatra.test.ScalatraTests$class.submit(ScalatraTests.scala:71)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest.submit(MyAppTest.scala:5)
[error] org.scalatra.test.ScalatraTests$class.get(ScalatraTests.scala:127)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest.get(MyAppTest.scala:5)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(MyAppTest.scala:10)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(MyAppTest.scala:10)
[error] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer()I
[error] org.eclipse.jetty.testing.HttpTester.generate(HttpTester.java:225)
[error] org.scalatra.test.ScalatraTests$class.submit(ScalatraTests.scala:46)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest.submit(MyAppTest.scala:5)
[error] org.scalatra.test.ScalatraTests$class.submit(ScalatraTests.scala:71)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest.submit(MyAppTest.scala:5)
[error] org.scalatra.test.ScalatraTests$class.get(ScalatraTests.scala:127)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest.get(MyAppTest.scala:5)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(MyAppTest.scala:10)
[error] com.example.MyAppTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(MyAppTest.scala:10)
```

This is the only search result that has turned up so far:
[Fragment Evaluation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419450/fragment-evaluation-error).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
-f

Comment: I don't know for sure but could it be that you are not using the proper Jetty library? I notice that the "flush" method has changed between jetty 6 and jetty 7. This could cause a "method not found error" which would explain the strange "org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer()I" signature in the exception message. This would also explain why this is a "fragment evaluation error" as explained in the link you mentioned.

Comment: If you give a go at the latest specs2-1.10-SNAPSHOT, you should get a better message for "fragment evaluation error" showing 'NoSuchMethodError' when that happens.

Comment: I just transformed my comments into a regular answer. I hope that's the right one :-)

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  It was the Jetty library.  I tried the 1.10-SNAPSHOT of specs2 and it didn't reveal a 'NoSuchMethodError', but the test works after rolling jetty-webapp back from 8.0.3.v20111011 to 7.6.0.v20120127.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a conflict in your dependencies, more specifically with the Jetty library version. Since the "flush" method on `HttpGenerator` has changed between Jetty 6 and Jetty 7, you might be getting a "NoSuchMethodFoundError" which explains the strange "org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer()I" signature in the exception message.

This also explains why you get a "fragment evaluation error" and not a regular failure as explained in the link you mentioned.

If you give a go at the latest specs2-1.10-SNAPSHOT, you will get a better message for "fragment evaluation error" showing 'NoSuchMethodError' when that happens. This will help you diagnosing the issue faster.

Answer (score 1):

Still unsure of the root cause, but the test executes successfully after rolling jetty-webapp back from 8.0.3.v20111011 to 7.6.0.v20120127.

Comment: Please help get better responses to questions by asking better questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask